# Algorithm for discrete similarity metric 

Tags: algorithm, comparison, machine-learning, similarity

Given that I have two lists that each contain a separate subset of a common superset, is
there an algorithm to give me a similarity measurement?

Example:

A =  { John, Mary, Kate, Peter } and B = { Peter, James, Mary, Kate }

How similar are these two lists? Note that I do not know all elements of the common superset.

Update: 
I was unclear and I have probably used the word 'set' in a sloppy fashion. My apologies.
Clarification: Order is of importance.
If identical elements occupy the same position in the list, we have the highest similarity for that element.
The similarity decreased the farther apart the identical elements are.
The similarity is even lower if the element only exists in one of the lists.

I could even add the extra dimension that lower indices are of greater value, so a a[1] == b[1] is worth more than a[9] == b[9], but that is mainly cause I am curious.

Comment: A good similarity measurement depends on the constraints of the data and the application. Does order matter?

Comment: Thanks, Holstebroe. A clarification is in order; the order is significant for the similarity. if A_1 and B_1 both was John that would be "more similar"

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I think many of them are correct and valid. Unfortunately I can only set one to accepted answer, which annoys me, because I'd like to give you all credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would explore two strategies:

1. Treat the lists as sets and apply set ops (intersection, difference)
2. Treat the lists as strings of symbols and apply the Levenshtein algorithm

Comment: Interesting. How would you handle an element that only exists in one of the lists with Levenshtein? This is one of my issues with the problem. I can calculate a "cost/penalty" for distance, but what is the cost of not being present at all in one of the lists.

Comment: Assuming your problem can be 'levenshteined', an element contained in A but not in B should reflect as an insertion.

Answer (score 13):

The ***Jaccard Index*** (*aka Tanimoto coefficient)* is used precisely for the use case recited in the OP's question.

The Tanimoto coeff, *tau*, is equal to ***Nc*** *divided by* ***Na*** + ***Nb - Nc***, *or*

```
tau = Nc / (Na + Nb - Nc)
```

- ***Na***, number of items in the first set
- ***Nb***, number of items in the second set
- ***Nc***, intersection of the two sets, or the number of unique items
  common to both a and b

Here's Tanimoto coded as a Python function:

```
def tanimoto(x, y) :
  w = [ ns for ns in x if ns not in y ]
  return float(len(w) / (len(x) + len(y) - len(w)))
```

Comment: Why reinvent this? Good answer.

Comment: In the discrete case (as in this situation), this is sometimes also known as the Jaccard metric (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have *sets* (i.e., an element is simply either present or absent, with no count attached) and only two of them, just adding the number of shared elements and dividing by the total number of elements is probably about as good as it gets.

If you have (or can get) counts and/or more than two of them, you can do a bit better than that with something like [cosine simliarity](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Cosine_Similarity.aspx) or [TFIDF](http://www.scribd.com/doc/10552567/TFIDF) (term frequency * inverted document frequency).

The latter attempts to give lower weighting to words that appear in all (or nearly) all the "documents" -- i.e., sets of words.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of "similarity measurement?"  If all you want is how many items in the set are in common with each other, you could find the cardinality of A and B, add the cardinalities together, and subtract from the cardinality of the union of A and B.

Comment: Well, I was unclear. I am quite surprised at the amount of activity and quality of answers here. Positively surprised! The "similarity" in my case includes order, so the greater the distance is between to identical elements, the less similar they are. At the same time if the element is not present at all in one of the lists it has to be less similar than if it was present in both, but at different position.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters you can use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or other kind of [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)
.